# Prolog program to get an (integer) number as the sum of two integer squares, why does it not work?

Tags: prolog, numbers, clpfd, number-theory, logical-purity

I'm starting learning Prolog and I want a program that given a integer `P` gives to integers `A` and `B` such that `P = A² + B²`. If there aren't values of `A` and `B` that satisfy this equation, `false` should be returned

For example: if `P = 5`, it should give `A = 1` and `B = 2` (or `A = 2` and `B = 1`) because `1² + 2² = 5`.

I was thinking this should work:

```
giveSum(P, A, B) :- integer(A), integer(B), integer(P), P is A*A + B*B.
```

with the query:

```
giveSum(5, A, B).
```

However, it does not. What should I do? I'm very new to Prolog so I'm still making lot of mistakes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`integer/1` is a non-monotonic predicate. It is **not** a relation that allows the reasoning you expect to apply in this case. To exemplify this:

```
?- integer(I).
false.
```

**No integer exists**, yes? *Colour me surprised*, to say the least!

Instead of such non-relational constructs, use your Prolog system's **CLP(FD) constraints** to reason about integers.

For example:

```
?- 5 #= A*A + B*B.
A in -2..-1\/1..2,
A^2#=_G1025,
_G1025 in 1..4,
_G1025+_G1052#=5,
_G1052 in 1..4,
B^2#=_G406,
B in -2..-1\/1..2
```

And for concrete solutions:

```
?- 5 #= A*A + B*B, label([A,B]).
A = -2,
B = -1 ;
A = -2,
B = 1 ;
A = -1,
B = -2 ;
etc.
```

CLP(FD) constraints are completely pure relations that can be used in the way you expect. See **[clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)** for more information.

Other things I noticed:

- `use_underscores_for_readability_as_is_the_convention_in_prolog` instead `ofMixingTheCasesToMakePredicatesHardToRead`.
- use declarative names, **avoid** imperatives. For example, why call it `give_sum`? This predicate also makes perfect sense if the sum *is already given*. So, what about `sum_of_squares/3`, for example?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.

I have a few questions. It would be awesome if you could answer them.



What does 'a non-monotonic predicate' mean, what does /1 or /3 mean and what does the label() function do?


On the Internet I read "Assign a value to each variable in Vars. Labeling means systematically trying out values for the finite domain variables Vars until all of them are ground." for the function labeling(), but I don't really understand it.


Also thanks for noticing bad practice, I changed the name and will use underscores and declarative names in the future.

Comment: Please file separate questions for this. They are all worth discussing on their own: 1) definition of monotonicity and 2) what is "labeling"?  Only one of your question is simple enough to be answered in a comment: `f/3` is a **predicate indicator** denoting a predicate called `f` with 3 *arguments*. Note that we always talk about **predicates**, which are *more general* than *functions*. Great for the names! Finding and using good, declarative names that do justice to the predicates' **generality** is a very important aspect when programming in Prolog, and probably one of the harder ones.

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency sake, Prolog implementers have choosen - many,many years ago - some compromise. Now, there are chances your Prolog implements advanced integer arithmetic, like CLP(FD) does. If this is the case, mat' answer is perfect. But some Prologs (maybe a naive ISO Prolog compliant processor), could complain about missing label/1, and (#=)/2. So, a traditional Prolog solution: the technique is called *generate and test*:

```
giveSum(P, A, B) :-
  ( integer(P) -> between(1,P,A), between(1,P,B) ; integer(A),integer(B) ),
  P is A*A + B*B.
```

between/3 it's not an ISO builtin, but it's rather easier than (#=)/2 and label/1 to write :)

Anyway, please follow mat' advice and avoid 'imperative' naming. Often a description of the relation is better, because Prolog it's just that: a relational language.